# Boostrap 3.0 Modal and Elevate zoom glitch

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, zooming

I have Elevate Zoom working within a bootstrap 3 modal element and all works fine after following an answer found here:

[ElevateZoom don't work in bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742159/elevatezoom-dont-work-in-bootstrap-modal)

Using the code given in the answer to the link above I have elevate zoom kicking in when a modal is launched. except when I close the modal I still get an area on my page that is invisible but when I hover over it, the enlarged (zooming) image is still shown in the corner of the page.

The code I used is based off this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $("#zoom_05").elevateZoom({
            zoomType: "inner",
            cursor: "crosshair"
        });
    })
});
```

I'm guessing this activates the elevate zoom script but does not kill the zoom plugin when I close the modal so I am still getting an active area when I go back to the page.

Using the inspector I see every time I open the modal a new instance of the following code is added to my HTML:

```
<div class="zoomContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 51293px; height: 402px; width: 568px;></div>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is someones answer/code snippet from internet. I used it while back and it's fine. 
Probably solved already- but for other who might find this thread:

Try this:

```
  jQuery('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

    jQuery.removeData(jQuery('#zoom_05'), 'elevateZoom');//remove zoom instance from image
    jQuery('.zoomContainer').remove();// remove zoom container from DOM
  });
```

Comment: This was the best solution I got so far, because of this I was able to solve a bug in the zooming functionality of my software, thanks a lot.