# implement elevate zoom on bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, elevatezoom

I am trying to use `elevate zoom` in a modal using bootstrap.

I tried everything and unfortunately had no result.

I would appreciate if someone could give me any similar sample

Comment: you realize this only works for images don't you?

Comment: yes i do
i have an image on a Bootstrap Modal which i want to zoom on it

Comment: can you provide code preferably a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I manage to solve it looking at [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742159/elevatezoom-dont-work-in-bootstrap-modal), but changing the *zoomType* to *lens* mode ([see docs](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#lens-zoom)).

So my code, to use elevate zoom in my modal, is:

1) Adjust Css:

```
.zoomContainer{ z-index: 9999;}
.zoomWindow{ z-index: 9999;}
```

2) Call te plugin when the modal is ready:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#zoom_05").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "lens",
        lensShape: "round",
        lensSize: 300
    });
});
```

As you can see, i used also the lensSize option to 300, to make the zoom bigger; That's because the [Mousewhell zoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#mousewheel) has some problem when in a boostrap modal, meanwhile the lens mode is a fast solution already working as it is.